# GCM notification that it received a new registration ID, or that existing ID is invalid?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging and I get a registration ID per device without issues.
However, according to the documentation from Google the registration ID may change if the device gets a new OS, or for any other reason.

So my question is, since the registration ID is given by Google, is there a way to get some sort of notification or callback saying that the existing registration ID is invalid, or that there is a new registration ID without having to get a new registration ID every time the application starts?

I could also set a timer to only get the registration ID every X number of days, but I wanted to know if anyone has found a way to check, without calling google for a registration id, if the existing (stored) registration id is still valid for this device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible without having 2 items to compare. What I do is store the GCM id into `SharedPreferences`, and then compare the current GCM id Google provides me upon registration and then determine whether the registration ID is still valid or not, and that's what the GCM documentation recommends to do.

Comment: Yeah that's obviously a good option, but I'm trying to avoid the call to Google to get a registration ID. I basically want to assume my current registration ID is valid unless "something" notifies me that is not. But I would like this "something" to be a local thing and not another extra network call.

Comment: That's what I wanted to make clear in my answer: The only one that can determine whether your ID is still valid is Google, and you may only know that by invoking the registration method. As documented, there's not a clear event that might make invalid an existing ID: no approximate expiration date nor something similar, so I guess the only one thing left is doing it this way.